# Freeform and MSM

Tags: solspace-freeform, multi-site-manager

I'm using EE 2.7.2 with Freeform 4.1.3 and Multiple Site Manager.

Works fine on the main site bit not on the second site. After completing the form takes me to mydomain.com/?ACT=35 and no submission in the CP or notification received.

Answer (score 1):

From [this Solspace thread](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/16564/#61594):

> Do you have a www redirect in your .htaccess? If so, make sure your
>   site configuration in ExpressionEngine has www in front of all of the
>   links, otherwise any EE created links, like Freeform’s actions, will
>   not have www and thus Apache will redirect, losing the post data.